# Rails turbolinks affect my content layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

When I enabled the turbolinks in my rails app, some of the content layout been affected and not aligned properly. But if I refresh the page then the content is aligned properly.

Comment: are you using `turbolinks 5?`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Turbolinks 5

Comment: i suggest try using `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` if you have not and include the `compatibility.coffee`  in your javascripts/compatibility.coffee. you can find the file at https://github.com/mrvncaragay/HyraV2/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/compatibility.coffee

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't make any difference. For the form submission page, I'm using the bootstrap grid system, I think it's the reason that the alignment of the content changed when turbolinks is fired. Other form submission page I did not use the bootstrap grid system and they work fine.

Comment: i see, i had the same problem with turbolinks 5 and i did what i said and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

After adding turbolinks,
remove below Two link in views/applicatios.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

it works for me..

Comment: It was added. But the problem hasn't solved. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Actually jquery loading more than one time so that problem occure. I faced same problem, and i find out the extra jquery calling link and removed after that its works good.